# Batch just crashes after too many ping attempts

Tags: batch-file, ping

I try to find out of a list of similar addresses, if I can ping some of those.
But after about 304 ping attemps/fails, the script just crashes.

```
@echo off

echo Start
set /A PORT=0
call:start
echo Finished
pause

:start
set /A PORT=%PORT%+1
set ADRESS=http://Adress.servehttp.com:%PORT%
ping /n 1 %ADRESS%
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo %ADRESS% >> results.log)
if %PORT% LEQ 65535 (call:start) ELSE pause
```

Comment: you can't ping a web address or a specific port, just a server: `ping Adress.servehttp.com`

Comment: You should be using `Set "PORT=0"` instead of `set /A PORT=0`, and `Set /A PORT +=1` or `Set /A PORT=PORT+1` instead of `set /A PORT=%PORT%+1`.

Comment: @Stephan Can you tell me how it is possible then to ping those. I mean if ping doesnt work is there anything else I can do to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `start` function is recursive and you have reached the stack limit allowed for a batch script which is usually very low.

You can solve this problem by using a loop instead.

Comment: changing `if %PORT% LEQ 65535 (call:start) ELSE pause` to `if %PORT% LEQ 65535 (goto :start) ELSE pause` should suffice to do that.